# TFS build web application missing BIN for Wix Installer

Tags: dll, build, wix, bin

I added into Solution(contains 30projects) Wix Installer, which is supposed to pack  web service folder. Among files i want to pack is BIN file with plenty of dlls. On local with Release mode it works fine, however if i run TFS 2013 build definition over solution i get these:

> `C:\Builds\1\ABCD_02\WixInstaller\WSwixInstaller\filesToBeInstalled.wxs (97)`: 
>   
> The system cannot find the file `'C:\Builds\1\ABCD_02\WixInstaller\WSwixInstaller\..\..\..\ABC WS\bin\ABC.Components.DataAccess.Lib.Utils.dll'`.

I asked my colleage who administrate server and he told me that BIN folder isn't created in 'expected' location.

Now i don't have access to server and colleage is unreacheable, is here rule where binaries for all project/within solution are stored?

Update:

Somehow we overlook BIN folder - 'as configured' is and was set in definition however files still couldn't be found - problem was in build order(weirdly in VS2010 was correct) setting dependency wix project on target project helped - problem was that wix project was builded before target one.

Answer (score 0):

Team Build creates uses a MsBuild parameter to redirect the build output of projects. If you need your Wix Installer to package up content that has been redirected, your installer script must be aware of this redirection happening.

The output structure of team build looks like

```
Build Agent Root
+- Unique build folder
 +- src             <- This is where your Wix project is placed
 +- bin             <- This is where Team Build redirects the project outputs to.
 +- Test            <- This is where Test Results are stored
```

This allows Team Build to figure out which outputs to copy to the drop location with a lot more accuracy, but it breaks any scripts that have hardcoded (or relative) paths to build outputs.

There is hope though, you can use the `$(OutDir)` or `$(OutputPath)` parameter to find the location Team Build has been configured to drop your binaries. You can use the `'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'==''` and/or `'$(TeamBuildConstants)'==''` to detect whether your Wix Script runs in Visual Studio or in Team Build.

That way you can define multiple source locations for your Wix packages or to set the base directory to a certain value and use that variable in your wix scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you simply want your team build to match your bin structure when running in visual studio, set the 'output location' parameter in your build definition to 'as configured' - see this link for details:
http://blog.stangroome.com/2014/02/10/override-the-tfs-team-build-outdir-property-in-tfs-2013/